# apache php > users requests

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, request, response

Hi my question is how the data flow works exactly in Apache web server + PHP.

When user access to url: localhost/index.php and in same time when another user access the same url i guess requests are executes one by one (not multi-threaded) and the first user get response then other one.

the question is: if somehow the first request stay in loop for long time like 1min the other users should wait the first request to finish then their requests to be finished in order to get response from Apache web server + PHP?
if answer is yes (other users should wait in queue): can we make requests to be executed in parallel (multi-thread) in order to prevent waiting in queue

Comment: Apache has several multi-threading models to choose from and PHP has several SAPIs available. In practice, it's irrelevant from the coding point of view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whilst PHP may be single threaded, Apache can run multi-process and multi-threaded.  This allows many requests to be executed simultaneously.  You can configure how many simultaneous requests in fact.

You can actually see Apache serving these requests live, see which are waiting, and which are being served via mod_status (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html).

Comment: how about the same script is called to be executed and first request freeze more then 1min?

Comment: Do you mean with two different users? In that case, yes. Apache will serve many, many users all at the same time. You can consider it like many, many Apache servers all working independently and not caring about what the others are doing even though it's just one installation of Apache.

Comment: i have a script that run 8hour after i call it from browser but when i try to open some other script from another browser tab i get only loading like waiting for response(chrome issue should be) but if i open from another browser(ie9) i can get the response asap, this prove that apache is multi-threaded.

Comment: That is due to PHP's session file locking for the duration of the script execution. Solutions are either to use non file-based storage or call session_write_close(); to free the lock. See this post - http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/416-PHP-and-Async-requests-with-file-based-sessions.html.

Answer (score 4):

Apache has multiple threads so multiple PHP scripts can run at once.

Webservers such as Nginx use an event driven architecture. Asynchronous I/O and all that jazz.

Webservers usually have some sort of mechanism to enable them to handle more than 1 request at a time, or at least make it seem like they can.

Apache uses threads, Nginx uses an event loop, but they are not serial in the sense that you want. The reason is very simple: it wastes resources. While your PHP script is waiting for the harddisk to move to the right position so you can read a block from a file you're reading you might as well be doing something else, ie. handle another request that doesn't require I/O right now.

If it's crucial some request finishes before other users make requests you should consider switching to a more decoupled asynchronous architecture. I don't know how invested you are in your current solution. Event handling can be implemented as simply as a simple poll or even a [long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

Comment: as i can understand from your answer apache is multi-threaded and executes parallel requests in same time in theory. but how about if same script is called to be executed and first request freeze more then 1min? the second request will be executed in same time or will wait to finish first request?